# Como criar essa view no postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query, view

```
CREATE VIEW grafico AS SELECT AVG(realizacao) , AVG(estima), AVG(fisiologica),AVG(seguranca),AVG(social) FROM necessidade;
```

Estou tentando criar uma view que traz a media de cinco colunas da tabela necessiadade, mas não consigo criar essa view com a query acima.

O postgres diz que estou usando a função AVG  mais de uma vez.

Segue a minha tabela necessidade:

```
CREATE TABLE necessidade
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  realizacao integer,
  estima integer,
  fisioologica integer,
  seguranca integer,
  social integer,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simulei aqui uma query e não verifiquei qualquer impedimento com o número de vezes que a função é usada.
Talvez mostrando um pouco mais dos dados que está usar se possa analisar melhor a consulta.

assim dá erro:

```
create or replace view teste as
select avg(x.col1), avg(x.col2), avg(x.col3)
```

assim está correto:

```
create or replace view teste as
select avg(x.col1) as avgcol1, avg(x.col2) as avgcol2, avg(x.col3) as avgcol3
from
(
select 13 as col1, 19 as col2, 44 as col3
union all
select 14 as col1, 39 as col2, 12 as col3
union all
select 23 as col1, 11 as col2, 10 as col3
union all
select 43 as col1, 79 as col2, 9 as col3) as x
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, editei a pergunta! Poderia explicar melhor essa sua resposta. Votei em sua resposta , deu certo aqui!

Comment: @PenaPintada, a alias x representa a consulta da sua tabela "necessidade", e o select é a consulta que me dá o resultado da média (avg) das colunas selecionadas. Através dessa consulta, criei uma view e não deu qualquer erro. Para tirar as dúvidas, crie uma view com essa consulta que dei de exemplo e me diga o resultado.

Comment: Eu ja havia feito uma consulta como essa a muito tempo atrás mas me esqueci como era a query, obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: só para complementar e esse é o seu erro, para gerar a view terá que adicionar o nome das colunas. editei a resposta inicial para ficar completo.